Linear gradient banding issue
*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: GothamRndMedium, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;

}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'GothamRndMedium';
    src: url('fonts/gothamrnd_medium.otf') format('opentype');
}

body {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom left, pink 0%, green 100%);)
}

This is my code. I am trying to get a smooth transition between two colors but for some reason it makes these bands instead of it being a clean look. See images for what I'm trying to get and what i am getting. I am actually watching someone code it but there's shows differently. Can someone help me figure out what needs to be changed in my code to fix this? :)  What i am getting
Increase Color Stops in Gradient:

Added more intermediate color stops in the linear gradient to create smoother transitions between colors.
body { padding: 0; margin: 0; background: linear-gradient(to bottom left, blue 0%, #0052a4 25%, #00aaff 50%, #00ffaa 75%, green 100%); } 
still gave me banding

I also Specified colors using rgba values to increase the precision of color transitions.
Still gave me banding.
I opened it in an actual browser and not the live preview in vs code and the banding was still there.
I saw an option for Dithering but it seemed a bit much and i wasn't sure if that's what i need to actually do.
I have also checked a few stackoverflow posts about this and the issue seems to be different that what i am experiencing.

That's not banding, it's the background being repeated.
Like so...


*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: GothamRndMedium, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'GothamRndMedium';
  src: url('fonts/gothamrnd_medium.otf') format('opentype');
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom left, pink 0%, green 100%);
  )
}

div {
  padding: 1em;
  outline: 1px solid grey;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>



Just add background-repeat: no-repeat and probably min-height: 100vh on the body


body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom left, pink 0%, green 100%);
  ) background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

div {
  padding: 1em;
  outline: 1px solid grey;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>




thank you so much. I thought it was banding. My mistake :) Thank you again for the assist because i didn't know what was going on.
